# Confusion with automorphisms of a projective variety with ample or antiample canonical class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, automorphism-group, divisors-algebraic-geometry

**Question**. Suppose $X$ is a smooth irreducible projective variety over a field $k$. Let $\omega_{X/k}=\bigwedge^{\dim X} \Omega_{X/k}$ be the canonical sheaf with associated divisor $K_X$. Suppose there is an integer $m$ so that $mK_X$ is very ample. Why is there an injection from $\operatorname{Aut}(X/k)$ to the automorphisms of the global sections of $mK_X$?

**My understanding**. I think I can prove that if $f$ is a $k$-automorphism of $X$, then $f^*\Omega_{X/k}\cong \Omega_{X/k}$ because they both satisfy the same univeral property. I think if $mK_X$ is very ample, then $X\cong \operatorname{Proj} \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes mn})$, which is Proj of a graded ring generated in degree $1$, so automorphisms of this ring are determined by what happens on the degree-1 piece, or $H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes m})$. Therefore if a map is the identity on $H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes m})$ it must be the identity on $X$.

**My issues**. I'm pretty unsure about whether my understanding is correct here and I'd like to check my understanding or see a correct proof if mine is flawed. I also have a concern that fact that for a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$, we have $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L})\cong k$. Shouldn't this be saying that there are no interesting maps $f^*\omega_{X/k}\to \omega_{X/k}$, since $f^*\omega_{X/k}\cong \omega_{X/k}$? This seems clearly wrong, but I don't fully understand why (is it possible that maybe $f^*\omega_{X/k}\cong \omega_{X/k}$ is not true as $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules? this is my only guess).

Comment: Are you sure that $X\cong \operatorname{Proj} \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes mn})$? Ampleness gives you an embedding $X\to \mathbb{P}H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes m}).$ As an example, consider $X=\mathbb{P}^k$

Comment: @IDC For $X\cong\Bbb P^1$ and $m=-1$, I get $\operatorname{Proj} k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ which is actually $\Bbb P^1$. I'm pretty sure the embedding you're describing is coming from the map $Sym(H^0(\omega^{\otimes m})) \to \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(\omega^{\otimes mn})$ which is evaluating a polynomial at the sections, basically.

Comment: You are right, I was being stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ m $ is a red herring anyway: replacing $ mK_X $ by $ K_X $ does not change anything in the following, so we'll assume $ K_X $ itself is very ample.

Anyway, any automorphism $ f $ of $ X $ preserves the canonical bundle. Hence it induces an automorphism of the vector space $ H^0(X, K_X) $ and this automorphism in turn induces an automorphism $ \tilde{f} $ of the projective space $ \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, K_X)^{\vee})  $. Let $ j : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, K_X)^{\vee}) $ be the embedding given by the very ample canonical class. There is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, K_X)^{\vee}) @>{\tilde{f}}>>\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, K_X)^{\vee}) \\
@AAA @AAA\\
X @>{f}>> X
\end{CD}

That is to say the automorphism $ f $ lifts to an automorphism of the ambient projective space given by the canonical embedding. Now it is obvious that $ Aut(X) $ injects into $ Aut(H^0(X,K_X)) $. This argument will also show that $ Aut(X) $ is infact finite if you admit that the field is complex numbers.

Your mistake: it is not true in general that any automorphism of $ X = \operatorname{Proj}(R) $ comes from an automorphism of the degree one piece of $ R $.

Edit, to answer some questions:

(1) For any smooth varieties $ X $ and $ Y $ of equal dimension $ n $ and any morphism $ g : X \rightarrow Y $, the derivative $ dg $ induces a map of tangent bundles $ TX \rightarrow g^* TY $ and hence taking top exterior powers gives a map of line bundles $ \wedge^n dg \in \operatorname{Hom}(\omega_X^{-1}, g^* \omega_Y^{-1}) $. Seeing this as a global section of the line bundle $ \omega_X \otimes g^* \omega_Y^{-1} $, the zero locus of that global section is precisely the points $ x \in X $ where $ dg_x $ fails to give an isomorphism of tangent spaces $ TX_x $ and $ TY_{g(x)} $.

Now specialize to the case when $ Y = X $ and $ g $ is an automorphism in which case $ dg $ is obviously an isomorphism everywhere and hence $ \wedge^n dg $ is nowhere zero. This shows $ \omega_X \otimes g^* \omega_X^{-1} $ is trivial. Therefore any automorphism preserves the canonical bundle.

I didn't really check your way with the universal property of the cotangent bundle but this is my preferred way to see it.

(2) For any line bundle $ L $ on any scheme $ X $, $ \mathcal{H}om(L,L)  = \mathcal{O}_X $ so global sections of the structure sheaf give you endomorphisms of $ L $. If $ X $ is projective and $ k $ is algebraically closed, then indeed the global sections are just elements of $ k $. I don't see any contradiction here and I don't really understand what your question is. Obviously all morphisms are morphisms of $ \mathcal{O}_X $-modules, how could they possibly not be here?

(3) For the 'stupidest' example of my last line - which is not mine and I found it in a comment of Jack Huizenga, consider $ X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ and the embedding given by the very ample bundle $ \mathcal{O}(2,1) $ into $ \mathbb{P}^5 $. Then the obvious involution on $ X $ swaps $ \mathcal{O}(2,1) $  to $ \mathcal{O}(1,2) $ so cannot come from an automorphism of the ambient $ \mathbb{P}^5 $.

(4) For ANY bundle, there is a pullback map of sections. Concretely in this case, there is a pullback of sections $ f^* : H^0(X, \omega_X) \rightarrow H^0(X, f^* \omega_X) $ given by $ s $ mapping to $ s \circ f $. Additionally here we know that $ f $ is an automorphism so the pullback map is a linear automorphism of VECTOR SPACES. This has nothing to do with canonical bundle being preserved, until now because apriori I have never said that $ f^* \omega_X $ is the same as $ \omega_X $.. but I will say it in the next paragraph.

Now aditionally (electric boogaloo) we know there is an isomorphism $ f^* \omega_X \rightarrow \omega_X $ given by $ df $ (which of course must be multiplication by a scalar by point (2)). The induced map on global sections will be called $ \Gamma(df) : H^0(X, f^* \omega_X) \rightarrow H^0(X, \omega_X) $ and this is of course, multiplication by the same scalar df.

The composition $ \Gamma(df) \circ f^* : H^0(X, \omega_X) \rightarrow H^0(X, \omega_X) $ is the map inducing the top arrow.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a few followups: can you comment on why automorphisms preserve the canonical bundle (is my proof ok?), can you address the issue with $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\omega,\omega)=k$, and can you provide a counterexample for the last line?

Comment: If $f:\mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-morphism of line bundles, then the action on global sections is multiplication by a constant in $k$, and so the induced map on global sections doesn't give any interesting automorphisms. That's what I was confused about.

Comment: @HankScorpio Edited with more details.

Comment: @HankScorpio ok, multiplication by constants may not be interesting but why is it clearly wrong? The bundles are isomorphic, the isomorphism is given by multiplication by a nonzero constant, after all.

Comment: If the automorphism induces a $\mathcal{O}_X$-automorphism of the line bundle, then it has to be multiplication by a constant from the field on global sections, then the induced morphisms in the top row of your diagram is the identity, and so $f$ must be the identity too. But there are clearly non-identity $f$ running around. (Thank you for your attention with the followups, by the way.)

Comment: @HankScorpio sorry, but you have completely missed the point. Automorphisms of the VECTOR SPACE of global sections of the line bundle need not come from automorphisms of the line bundle itself. The top row is not coming from the identity. It is coming from a section s being pulled back by the automorphism f ON X, i.e. s maps to s compose f.

Comment: Now s compose f is apriori a section of $ f^* \omega_X $ but we can identify it with $ \omega_X $ by multiplication by a non zero number (which does not change anything as far as the induced map on projective spaces is concerned).

Comment: Well, at least that makes two of us who agree I'm a little confused. Let me try to state things a bit more clearly: given an automorphism $f:X\to X$, which satisfies $\omega\stackrel{\cong}{\to}f^*\omega$, I would think that the induced map on global sections $H^0(\omega)\to H^0(f^*\omega)$ can be obtained from taking global sections of some map in $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\omega,f^*\omega)$. But if $f^*\omega\cong\omega$, then $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\omega,f^*\omega)\cong \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\omega,\omega) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$. What's wrong with this?

Comment: "I would think that the induced map on global sections..." I'll say this a second time, and the last time. This sentence is exactly where you are completely wrong. I edited my answer one last time. I've spent too much time on this and I won't reply any more.

Comment: Your final edit has cleared things up. Thank you for your assistance, apologies for being bone-headed about this issue.